# how will start to create AJAX request that get data from server

Tags: jquery

how to list goods in the html document using Ajax? goods are stored on the server. need to make a request-ajax. I just do not know how. I have server that created early.  server will  be  return json.  I must just create get request in javaScript document & will bridge to html.

Comment: I suggest you take it from the top: [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code in your client (JAVASCRIPT)
response will contain your json format from your server.
change "YUOR-SERVER-ADDRESS" to your server address that return the 'goods' in json format

```
<script>
var response = null;

function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
       response = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","YOUR-SERVER-ADDRESS",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

if you want to "decode" json format you can use:

`var myJsonObj = JSON.parse(response);`